# Cubic Bezier with fixed length. How to limit the control points to certain ranges?

Tags: graphics, graphics2d

I know. This question was already answered but I not a mathematician and really I didn't understand the answers.
I need a Cubic bezier and need to fix the 2 control points so that the total length of the curve will never change. So I need to limit the control points to certain ranges I suppose. How can I range the control points in a way that starting point is always fixed and ending point variable ?

Answer (score 1):

Cubic Bezier spline is defined by four points: `P0`, `P1`, `P2`, `P3`. Where `P0` is a starting point, `P1` and `P2` are control points and `P3` is an ending point of the curve.
In general, length of linear spline ``` P0``P1``P2``P3 ``` is a upper bound for Bezier curve length and length of ``` P0``P3 ``` is a lower bound. In other words, all Bezier curves for which length ``` P0``P1``P2``P3 ``` is the equal, also have the same length of the Bezier curve.

Considering quadratic Bezier spline with fixed starting point `P0` and ending point `P2`, then geometrical place for all possible `P1` for fixed length Bezier curves will be an ellipse with focal points in `P0` and `P2`.

Considering cubic Bezier spline with fixed starting point `P0` and ending point `P2`, geometrical place for `P1` and `P2` for fixed length Bezier curves is not a curve any more, but a subspace. But applying additional restrictions, for example, fixing `P2`, will simplify it to a planar curve. This will be again an ellipse with focal points in `P0` and `P2`.